# cast back from supertype to child

Tags: java, casting

Let's say I have a super type (Shape) and two children (like Square, Circle).

I'm trying to make something like this:

```
Shape shape = someObject.getShape();

if (shape instanceof Square){
    shape = (Square) shape;
    // do this
} else if (shape instanceof Circle) {
    shape = (Circle) shape;
    // do that
}
```

Also, since getting instances doesn't seem a correct OO principle, is there another way doing that? Cheers.

**edit.** I'm not trying to invoke methods on them, I want to pass them to some methods that need their specific subtype.

**edit2** Basically I have a collection of type Shape so I can hold both type of subtypes in it. But when it comes to processing at one point, I need to know which of those two subclasses is, so I can pass it to a method that takes the subtype as an argument. I could easily use the supertype as argument but that wouldn't be secure, since I deal with subtype-specific data.

Comment: you might have to create a new instance like `Square square; if(shape instanceof Square) { square = (Square) shape; //do this}`

Comment: The better OO principle is to have a shared abstract method in the common supertype of both of them. Then, whatever the actual shape is, you can invoke the class-specific method using the supertype declaration

Comment: the problem is that I do not want to invoke any methods but to pass this object to another method that needs the subtype specifically

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to declare the variable properly, for example:

```
if (shape instanceof Square){
    Square square = (Square) shape;
    // do this with square
} else if (shape instanceof Circle) {
    Circle circle = (Circle) shape;
    // do that with circle
}
```

Comment: I thought using the same variable for holding, well, itself. Probably cannot do that :/

Comment: In Java you can call a methods that are declared to the variable type, not the actual assigne dobject. If some methods are overriden, their new version will be called.

Comment: Yeah I know that, I just need to pass the subtypes to different methods which have specific args for those specific class types...

Comment: I think, Shape is not instance of Sqare or Circle, is it?

Answer (score 1):

Once you declare a reference in Java you cannot change his type. When you do:

```
Shape shape = someObject.getShape();
```

You are saying: "store a reference to a Shape in the variable shape". Since you cannot change its type it has no sense doing

```
shape = (Square) shape;
```

because you are saying that shape (left side) is a Shape, no matter what is on the right side on the assignment.

Remember: once you declare a type for a reference you cannot change it.

Answer (score 1):

I do not really understand what you are trying to accomplish here, but off course you can differ cases in form of

```
shape.getClass().isAssignableFrom(Square.class) ? processSquare((Square)shape) : processCircle((Circle)shape)
```

There will be no Problem with that cast, if you first check the actual class.

**edit** Your shapes class type does not change :

```
Shape[] shapes = new Shape[]{new Circle()}
```

as you are looping through your shapes collection, when you call `shapes[0].getClass()` you will get the `Circle.class` type. So at the point where you iterating your shape collection and need to decide which type specific collection to call, you can call `shape.getClass().isAssignableFrom(Circle.class)` for example, to switch cases. Then you can cast the type and call the method you need. No need to hold your shape object in differnt collections

Comment: well I think your applications design is a bit messed up. But, apart from that, like it has been shown, the actuel class type of your instance does not change, despite from the supertype variable you are storing it. Ill edit my post to make that clear

Comment: I don't hold my shape object in different collections, when did I say that? :P I have one ArrayList<Shape>. I have a method, lets say cutSquareInHalf(Square sq). So when I get a shape object from the collection, I need to know if it's actually a square so I can cast it and pass it on that method.

Comment: the post that is marked as as the right answer told you to do so. I do not see any profit in doing this.

Comment: "I need to know if it's actually a square" -> shapes[0].getClass().isAssignableFrom(Square.class) -> returns true if this class is same or supertype of parameter class. So whats wrong with that? If you give me an argument againt this solution, Ill try to come up with some differnt solutions :)

Comment: I prefer instanceof because it returns true for any subtype as well. I'm pretty sure that your code works as well but I had implemented it like that since the beginning :) My previous comment was just for your last sentence "No need to hold your shape object in different collections"